# Fading in elements wrapped in <span> randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fade in the elements wrapped in span tags randomly. There are a few examples on stackoverflow, but I cannot get them them to work in my code.

**Also.. Is there a more elegant way of doing this than wrapping every single word in span tags?**

I am trying to turn akll the spans into an array, then select an element in that array at random, and fade it in via changing the opacity of that element, then remove it from the array
Here is a jsfiddle of myy attempt..

https://jsfiddle.net/jnghna9s/2/

My script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact").click(function() {
    var spans = $("#changingP span").get();

    for(var i =0; i < spans.length; i++) {    
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * spans.length);
        $(spans[index]).fadeTo(200, 1, function() {
        spans.splice(index,i);
        }
    })
});
});
```

Comment: Add a function that parses the text in your words container into tokens, and then using a .each() function wrap the tokens in the span tags. Then your function can work against the modified text. But you should maybe add a class name to the span tags, so that your function doesn't try to mess with ~every~ span on the page (in case you have other spans).

Comment: Here is a quick fiddle demonstrating my comment: https://jsfiddle.net/umo8swhv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use complete callback of [`fadeTo`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) method. Something like this would work:

```js
var spans = $('#changingP span').get();

function fadeIn() {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * spans.length);
    $(spans[index]).fadeTo(200, 1, function() {
        spans.splice(index, 1);
        if (spans.length) {
            fadeIn();
        }
    });
}

fadeIn();
```

```css
span {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="changingP">
<span>Want </span><span>to </span><span>get </span><span>in</span><span> contact</span><span> with </span><span>me</span><span>?</span>
    <br /><span>Email</span><span>: </span><span>edit</span><span>.</span><span>ed</span><span>email</span><span>@</span><span>gmail</span><span>.</span><span>com</span>
    <br /><span>Link</span><span>edI</span><span>n</span><span>: </span><span>http</span><span>s://w </span><span></span><span>ww.</span><span>lin</span><span>kedi</span><span>n.com</span><span>/</span><span>in/</span><span>edit</span><span>ed</span><span>email</span>

</p>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! How would I include the .js in brackets? Fairl new to web development and I'm not  totally sure what jsFiddle inserts for you..

Comment: Just put the code inside `$(function() { /** code from the answer **/ })`. I omitted it for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

@dfsq answer is good. For geeks like me interested in the jQuery-less version, the following will do too: (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/jnghna9s/4/))

```
function randomFade(elements) {
  var shownCount = 0,
      indexes = [];
  function appear(el) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var count = 10, i = setInterval(function() {
        el.style.opacity = (parseFloat(el.style.opacity) || 0) + 0.1;
          if (!count--) 
             clearInterval(i);
        }, 50);
    }, shownCount++*200); 
  }
  function shuffle(o){
    // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/
    // how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript#answer-6274381
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), 
      x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
  };
  for (var i = elements.length; i--;) indexes.push(i);
  indexes = shuffle(indexes);
  for (var f = indexes.length; f--;) appear(elements[indexes[f]]);
}
```

Comment: This seems like more work/code just to not use jQuery..?

Comment: @MattEm it's purely out of curiosity =)

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop logic is off. Try this

```
var maxDelay = 5000;
for(var i=0; i < $length; i++) {
    var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * maxDelay);
    $('span')eq(i).delay(random).css("opacity","1");
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `.` inbetween `$('span')` and `eq(i)`